# Groovy Better Approach to create comma separated string from Database Select Query

Tags: sql, string, oracle, groovy

I am trying to connect to oracle database table and pull the data and form the result in the form of comma separated values. I have written a sample code which works fine but wanted to have a better approach if the query is associated with more tables (joins), then the time is taken to get the output is more. Is there any better way of improving the performance.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

def temp="";
def temp1="";
sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","username", "password", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
sql.eachRow("select empid, empname FROM employee") {
    temp1=it.toRowResult().values().join(", ")
    if(temp=="") {
        temp=temp1;
    }else{
        temp=temp+"\n"+temp1
    }          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("yourfile.csv"), ',');
 Boolean includeHeaders = true;

 java.sql.ResultSet myResultSet = .... //your resultset logic here

 writer.writeAll(myResultSet, includeHeaders);

 writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select empid || ', ' || empname as NewValue FROM employee
in your query, then SQL work for you a little bit

Comment: I have tried this way and am getting result as an array. I am converting the array to string using the join method which is taking more time.Currently I am not writing this output to any of the file. I was expecting a better approach of how this can be achieved in Groovy.